# Implementing geofencing in a tabbed activity

Tags: java, android

Im new to android development. I followed a basic tutorial about geofencing on [Geofencing on tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639). I successfully created an app with geofencing. Im now trying to implement geofencing in a swipe tabbed activity, which I don't know if its possible. I have three java class which is the default main activity for the tabbed activity, the Fragment and the geofence handler class.

Below is the fragment class

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Third.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Third#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Third extends SupportMapFragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        ResultCallback<Status>{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;



    private MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
    // Create a Intent send by the notification
    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg );
        return intent;
    }

    public Third() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment First.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Third newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Third fragment = new Third();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // initialize GoogleMaps
        initGMaps();

        // create GoogleApiClient
        createGoogleApi();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_a, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch ( item.getItemId() ) {
            case R.id.geofence: {
                startGeofence();
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.clear: {
                clearGeofence();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    // Create GoogleApiClient instance
    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                    .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                    .addApi( LocationServices.API )
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Call GoogleApiClient connection when starting the Activity
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    private final int REQ_PERMISSION = 999;

    // Check for permission to access Location
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
        // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    // Asks for permission
    private void askPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");

    }

    // Verify user's response of the permission requested
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult()");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch ( requestCode ) {
            case REQ_PERMISSION: {
                if ( grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                    // Permission granted
                    getLastKnownLocation();

                } else {
                    // Permission denied
                    permissionsDenied();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // App cannot work without the permissions
    private void permissionsDenied() {
        Log.w(TAG, "permissionsDenied()");
        // TODO close app and warn user
    }

    // Initialize GoogleMaps
    private void initGMaps(){
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    // Callback called when Map is ready
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");
        map = googleMap;
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Fragment f = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick("+latLng +")");
        markerForGeofence(latLng);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClickListener: " + marker.getPosition() );
        return false;
    }

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    // Defined in mili seconds.
    // This number in extremely low, and should be used only for debug
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 900;

    // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates(){
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if ( checkPermission() )
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
        lastLocation = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }

    // Get last known location
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if ( checkPermission() ) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if ( lastLocation != null ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
                writeLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
        else askPermission();
    }

    private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {

        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void writeLastLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
    }

    private Marker locationMarker;
    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            if ( locationMarker != null )
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }


    private Marker geoFenceMarker;
    private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        // Define marker options
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            // Remove last geoFenceMarker
            if (geoFenceMarker != null)
                geoFenceMarker.remove();

            geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    }

    // Start Geofence creation process
    private void startGeofence() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
        if( geoFenceMarker != null ) {
            Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
            GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
            addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Geofence marker is null");
        }
    }

    private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
    private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 500.0f; // in meters

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence( LatLng latLng, float radius ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
                .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
                .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
                .addGeofence( geofence )
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
    private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    request,
                    createGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
        if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
            saveGeofence();
            drawGeofence();
        } else {
            // inform about fail
        }
    }

    // Draw Geofence circle on GoogleMap
    private Circle geoFenceLimits;
    private void drawGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawGeofence()");

        if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
            geoFenceLimits.remove();

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
                .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
                .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
                .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
        geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle( circleOptions );
    }

    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT = "GEOFENCE LATITUDE";
    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LON = "GEOFENCE LONGITUDE";

    // Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
    private void saveGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude ));
        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude ));
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Recovering last Geofence marker
    private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
        Log.d(TAG, "recoverGeofenceMarker");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

        if ( sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT ) && sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON )) {
            double lat = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, -1 ));
            double lon = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, -1 ));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lon );
            markerForGeofence(latLng);
            drawGeofence();
        }
    }

    // Clear Geofence
    private void clearGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "clearGeofence()");
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
                    // remove drawing
                    removeGeofenceDraw();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void removeGeofenceDraw() {
        Log.d(TAG, "removeGeofenceDraw()");
        if ( geoFenceMarker != null)
            geoFenceMarker.remove();
        if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
            geoFenceLimits.remove();
    }






    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
 }
}
```

I get the following errors in my fragment:
Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences'

```
private MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragment().findFragmentById(R.id.map)
```

Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment'

The helper class

```
public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // Handling errors
        if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
            Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        // Check if the transition type is of interest
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
            // Get the geofence that were triggered
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

            // Send notification details as a String
            sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
        }
    }


    private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        // get the ID of each geofence triggered
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
        }

        String status = null;
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
            status = "Entering ";
        else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            status = "Exiting ";
        return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void sendNotification(String msg ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = Third.makeNotificationIntent(
                getApplicationContext(), msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Third.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }


    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }
}
```

The tabbed activity returns 3 tabs, the other two tabs are empty. Can I also use multiple maps in a tabbed activity. Any help and guidance to best android development practices will be highly appreciated

Comment: There's nothing that a tabbed activity prevents. Have you tried just using one Fragment in an Activity? Did it work?

Comment: @cricket_007 I would first like to know why am I getting those two errors on the first fragment

Comment: Because you need to use a SupportMapFragment

Comment: @cricket_007 Is it also possible to send an SMS when the user enters into a geofence. Can u also provide me with sample code to do so

Comment: As stated, tabbed activity is not preventing anything from being done. That sounds like a completely separate question from the initial question, so I would suggest you make a new post and adding code you've tried to implement that feature